# Menu has black borders after using HDMI in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, context-menu

This has happened several times, and it's always after connecting to a TV through HDMI to do a presentation. It happens after disconnecting from the HDMI.

The menu is cropped to the right and bottom, and it has black borders. If the cursor goes over some of the black entries they get repainted, and sub-menus have it as well.

I can fix it only with a restart. Anything I can do about this problem?

[image]

**Edit::** My video card driver as requested:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to use an alternative method, forcefully end and restart, the explorer.exe process.

Comment: Does it only give black borders to explorer items? How do you share your screen and how do you close it? @Ramhound you've beat me by 58 seconds xD

Comment: Have you ensured you're using the latest driver for your video card?

Comment: @Ramhound I killed explorer from Process Explorer and started it again - no change.

Comment: Is it a laptop/tablet? Like Techie said, did you check for more recent video drivers? Is Windows 10 up-to-date? Did the device originally come with Windows 10? Please provide its exact make and model.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I added info about my graphics card driver from dxdiag - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE4BG.png.

Comment: Are you using a non-default Windows theme? Do you use a custom DPI resolution for the desktop and does it change when connecting to HDMI?

Comment: @harrymc No, it's a standard theme and I haven't changed the DPI.

Comment: Other than the menu truncation, do you see any other change on the screen from before and after connecting to HDMI? Like sizes of desktop icons, text or monitor.

Comment: @harrymc No, just the black menus. Also other colleagues in the office see the same problem since we were issued the same laptops.

Comment: What is the computer model and the video card? Your video driver is version 4481, but I can find [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26669/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-45-) a newer version 4627 of the Intel Graphics Driver. If you decide to try it, first take precautions : At least create a system restore point, and better have the installation media for your current driver.

Comment: @harrymc Actually there is NVIDIA GeForce 930MX under the Render tab in dxdiag. I hand't seen that because I had been looking at the Display tab.

Comment: So you have a second driver to update, although the Intel Graphics is probably responsible for the desktop display. For the Nvidia it's best to go to the [Driver page](http://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx) and use "Automatically find drivers" (requires Java or Internet Explorer).

Comment: @harrymc When updating the intel driver using their update utility I got an error saying that I have a customized driver by HP, and it should not be updated with a generic Intel driver, and a link - https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005469.html. Does this mean that it is not recommended to update any drivers? I don't want to mess up the laptop just for a crapshoot, which updating drivers usually is, kind of like "try recompiling the kernel" for linux questions.

Comment: Agreed : If this computer needs a customized driver it's better to be careful than sorry. If you have updated to Windows 10 from a previous version, the upgrade might have kept the previous driver that might have a slight problem with Windows 10. Better to search a Windows 10 driver on the HP support site. If you would like my help in this, I would need your computer model.

Comment: Windows 10 is very bad at video adapter driver management. Get the latest driver for chipset and video from intel's site and install those.

Comment: I had the same problem; also on an HP machine - this might be an unrelated driver issue in some HP-specific driver. Graphics driver seems unlikely because I had the problem with Intel integrated graphics as well as a dedicated Radeon card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer from this question - [Windows menus are black until mouseover](https://superuser.com/q/1203402/66282).

> A workaround that did fix the problem:
>
> Go to System Properties > Advanced > Performance > Settings > Visual Effects
> Uncheck "Fade or slide menus into view" (or simply choose "Adjust for best performance" to uncheck everything)
> Click "Apply"

[image]